# set a parameter value outside the maven plugin project

Tags: java, maven, plugins, parameters

Presently, I'm wroting a plugin in maven and I want to set there two parameters for pathes.

Now, the problem is, that I have to define that on the plugin itself or in its POM.xml.
But that's not what I want.

Is it possible to define the value of the parameter in the POM of the project where I want to use this plugin? In my opinion that will make more sense...

**EDIT:**
Okay, the the problem with writing values is resolved.
But how can I put two different parameters in one maven goal?

It's one way I tried to solve it:

```
    public class ParameterMojo extends AbstractMojo
    {
/**
 * @parameter
 * 
 * 
 * @throws MojoExecutionException
 * @throws MojoFailureException 
 */
private String path;
private String pathsave;

/**
 * logs path
 * logs pathsave
 * 
 * @throws MojoExecutionException
 * @throws MojoFailureException 
 */
```

POM:

```
   <plugin>
           <groupId>com.tup.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>versionsextra</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetFile>target/site/etwas/versionsextra.html</targetFile>
                <path>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configsys/dev/etc/deploy_env</path>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <name>Development</name>
                        <path>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configsys/dev/etc/deploy_env</path>
                        <pathsave>${basedir}/src/main/resources/configsys/dev/etc/test.txt</pathsave>
                    </environment>
                </environments>    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Can't you just add a configuration block for your plugin and set the values there?

Comment: yeah, my fault was that I made it with an expression and then I had to define it in properties section.

Comment: so @StevenPessall got another problem. This way I can only name one parameter. But I need two...

Comment: Can you post the source of your Mojo? It should be no problem to add mutliple parameters.

Comment: ok. maybe you can help me now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your MOJO defines a member "path", which matches the node "path" in your configuration. It also defines a member "pathsave", but there is no node "pathsave" in your pom below **configuration**. The node "pathsave" in the environment node is not relevant.

Have a look at the maven guide for plugin development. There are examples for Mojos with multiple parameters:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Comment: I read this guide a hundred times^^ and with only one parameter it works this way...

Comment: Can you add the part of your pom where you use your MOJO?